# SQL instances where I must use JOIN...ON and can't replace it with FROM...WHERE

Tags: sql, join

I've been learning SQL for the past couple of days, and it seems that JOIN...ON is a fairly common operator. But most of the time I find that if I write the same SQL code using FROM...WHERE, it will return the same result.

The below is a code taken from a SQL tutorial website

```
SELECT games.yr, city.country
FROM games JOIN city
ON (games.city = city.name)
```

But I recoded it into

```
SELECT games.yr, city.country
FROM games, city
WHERE(games.city = city.name)
```

and it still returns the same output. With this, it's really hard for me to grasp the concept of JOIN ON.

Can you provide an example in which JOIN ON is necessery and can't be replaced by FROM WHERE ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With just two tables, it's no big deal which you use. If you have more tables, however, it very quickly gets confusing as to what part of the where clause goes with which JOIN. Queries can become nearly unreadable. Additionally, there are some cases where the old Sql-89 `A,B` syntax is **ambiguous** as to meaning, and others where that syntax is not able to express what you need from the query at all... especially involving outer joins.

For example, let's take a look at this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON B.X = A.X AND B.Y = '1'
```

That's easy to convert to the old syntax, because it doesn't matter about the extra `AND` section:

```
SELECT * FROM A,B WHERE A.X = B.X and B.Y = '1'
```

But what about this one:

```
SELECT * 
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON B.X = A.X AND B.Y = '1'
```

Now it's not so clear what to do any more. It can matter for the query whether the `B.Y = '1'` expression is part of the JOIN or part of the WHERE, because that can determine which records are needed for the results. In this case, there is a `*=` sytnax that indicate that the clause is part of a join... but its possible to construct queries where that still doesn't account for every possible interpretation.

Today, many database professionals, myself included, will tell you to **never** use the older A,B syntax, and always use the new sql-92 syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Both the queries will result the same But we all prefer to use the `INNER JOIN` syntax.

```
SELECT games.yr, city.country
FROM games 
INNER JOIN city
ON (games.city = city.name)
```

`Inner Join` syntax is more **readable** and tells you which condition is used to Join the two tables.

Always keep the join conditions in `ON` clause and move the filters to `Where` clause. Clearly Inner Join syntax help's you to find the which is Join and which one is filter.

But it not the case with Old style `Comma Separated Join` everything will be in `where` clause.

Comment: Would this be a case of just language convention then? that, by convention, JOIN...ON is more widely used then the way I presented

Comment: @user3277633 Often, it is just convention. However, there are some things that JOIN ... ON can do that other syntax can't, and as you add more tables to a query that **readable** thing really starts to add up quickly. You may not see a difference now, but work with a few more database projects and you will.